# OCaml functors :: counter-intuitive behaviour

Tags: ocaml, functor

I am experimenting with the module language of OCaml (3.12.1), defining functors and signatures for modules and so on, mostly following the examples from [Chapter 2 of the OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual004.html) and I've stumbled, by accident, on a situation where apparently my mental model of how functors and module signatures work is flawed. I tried to narrow the situation I encountered to the shortest amount of code possible so don't ask what I am trying to accomplish, this is a totally contrived example to demonstrate the OCaml feature in question.

So, we have a functor that simply provides an identity function `f` and is parametrized by a module supplying the type of that function's input parameter. Totally contrived example like I said.

```
module type SOMETYPE = sig type t end ;;
module Identity = functor (Type: SOMETYPE) -> struct let f (x: Type.t) = x end ;;
```

Given the above, we proceed to define a module to supply the int type:

```
module IntType = struct type t = int end ;;
```

.. and then we use the functor to generate a module for the int identity function:

```
module IdentityInt = Identity(IntType) ;;
```

Sure enough the generated module and its `f` function behave as expected:

```
#IdentityInt.f(3) + 10 ;;
- : int = 13
```

The mental model of functors being functions that take modules as inputs and return modules seems to be serving us right so far. The `Identity` functor expects as input parameter a module of signature (module type) `SOMETYPE`, and indeed the module we supplied (`IntType`) has the correct signature and so a valid output module is produced (`IdentityInt`) whose `f` function behaves as expected.

Now comes the un-intuitive part. What if we would like to make it explicit that the supplied module `IntType` is indeed a `SOMETYPE` type of module. As in:

```
module IntType : SOMETYPE = struct type t = int end ;;
```

and then generate the functor's output module the same way as before:

```
module IdentityInt = Identity(IntType) ;;
```

... let's try to use the `f` function of the newly generated module:

```
IdentityInt.f 0 ;;
```

Whereupon the REPL complains with:

```
"Error: This expression [the value 0] has type int but an expression was expected of type IntType.t."
```

How can providing redundant but correct type information break the code? Even in case A the functor module `Identity` had to treat the `IntType` module as `SOMETYPE` type. So how come explicitly declaring `IntType` to be `SOMETYPE` type yields a different outcome?

Comment: Is it on purpose that the second `module IntType` is missing the `= int` part?

Comment: No, it's a typo on the copy-paste form my REPL. The second module IntType correctly reads: `module IntType : SOMETYPE = struct type t = int end` and you get exactly the same results that I describe above. I'll edit the post too to avoid any misunderstandings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `:` construct is different in the core language and in the module language. In the core language, it is an annotation construct. For example, `((3, x) : 'a * 'a list)` constrains the expression to have some type that is an instance of `'a * 'a list`; since the first element of the pair is an integer, `let (a, b) = ((3, x) : 'a * 'a list) in a + 1` is well-typed. The `:` construct on modules does not mean this.

The construct `M : S` *seals* the module `M` to the signature `S`. This is an opaque seal: only the information given in the signature `S` remains available when typing uses of `M : S`. When you write `module IntType : SOMETYPE = struct type t end`, this is an alternate syntax for

```
module IntType = (struct type t end : SOMETYPE)
```

Since the type field `t` in `SOMETYPE` is left unspecified, `IntType` has an abstract type field `t`: the type `IntType` is a new type, generated by this definition.

By the way, you probably meant `module IntType = (struct type t = int end : SOMETYPE)`; but either way, `IntType.t` is an abstract type.

If you want to specify that a module has a certain signature while leaving some types exposed, you need to add an explicit equality for these types. There's no construct to add all inferable equalities, because applying a signature to a module is usually meant for information hiding. In the interest of simplicity, the language only provides this one generative sealing construct. If you want to use the defined signature `SOMETYPE` and retain the transparency of the type `t`, add a constraint to the signature:

```
module IntType = (struct type t = int end : SOMETYPE with type t = int)
```

Comment: Yeah, its `module IntType = (struct type t = int end : SOMETYPE)` I meant; it was a copying mistake from my REPL (I edited the post to correct it). Still, like you say, one gets the same results. I understand now the `:` construct in modules in not an annotation but hides information instead although I am not sure I completely appreciate all the minutiae.

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the inferred signature when you don't write something explicitly:

```
# module IntType = struct type t = int end ;;
module IntType : sig type t = int end
```

The signature exposes that `t` is an `int`. Your signature, on the contrary:

```
# module IntType : SOMETYPE = struct type t = int end ;;
module IntType : SOMETYPE
```

is really:

```
# module IntType : sig type t end = struct type t = int end ;;
module IntType : sig type t end
```

This seems to solve your problem:

```
# module IntType : (SOMETYPE with type t = int) = struct type t = int end ;;
module IntType : sig type t = int end
# module IdentityInt = Identity(IntType) ;;
module IdentityInt : sig val f : IntType.t -> IntType.t end
# IdentityInt.f 0 ;;
- : IntType.t = 0
```

(you don't need the parens, but they help mentally parse). Basically, you expose the fact that t is an int with your signature. So that OCaml knows the equality IntType.t = int.

For more details of the internals, I'll leave it to more knowledgeable people.

Answer (score 5):

When you write:

```
module IntType : SOMETYPE = struct type t = int end ;;
```

You are constraining the signature of `InType` to be exactly `SOMETYPE`. This means, for instance, that the type `t` is now becoming an abstract type (whose implementation is unknown to the typer).

So `IdentityInt.f` type is still `IntType.t -> IntType.t`, but, by using a signature constraint, you've explicitly removed the equation `IntType.t = int` from the typer knowledge. The error message you get tells you exactly that.

Answer (score 5):

Your key error was here:

> module IntType : SOMETYPE = struct type t end ;;

When you ascribe the signature `SOMETYPE`, it's an opaque ascription, and the identity with `int` is lost.  Type `IntType.t` is now an abstract type.

You need instead to ascribe the signature `SOMETYPE with type t = int`.

This transcript shows the difference:

```
# module type SOMETYPE = sig type t end;;
module type SOMETYPE = sig type t end
# module IntType : SOMETYPE with type t = int = struct type t = int end;; 
module IntType : sig type t = int end
# module AbsType : SOMETYPE = struct type t = int end;;                 
module AbsType : SOMETYPE
```

The language-design issues around modules and ascription are well covered in the lead designer's [1994 paper on modules, types, and separate compilation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/papers/xleroy-manifest_types-popl94.pdf).  The hairy math parts can all be skipped.

Comment: Thanks, it's actually `module IntType: SOMETYPE = struct type t = int end ;;` that I used (I made a copying mistake from my REPL but now have updated the post). Still, one gets exactly the same results either way. The type `t` is lost even though specified and only when using the construct you and other posters suggested (namely `module IntType : SOMETYPE with type t = int = struct type t = int end` do you I get the expected results. Still, in my view not exactly the most intuitive to grasp concept or syntax and rather glossed over at the OCaml manual.

Comment: @Menelaos, opaque ascription is much beloved of us modules guys.  These issues are illuminated by Xavier Leroy's 1994 paper from POPL.  I'd added a link to my answer.