# OCaml module types and separate compilation

Tags: module, ocaml

I am reading through [OCaml lead designer's 1994 paper on modules, types, and separate compilation.](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/papers/xleroy-manifest_types-popl94.pdf) (kindly pointed to me by [Norman Ramsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41661/norman-ramsey) in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778595/ocaml-functors-counter-intuitive-behaviour) ). I understand that the paper discusses the origins of OCaml's present module type / signature system. It it, the author proposes opaque interpretation of type declarations in signatures (to allow separate compilation) together with manifest type declarations (for expressiveness). Attempting to put together some examples of my own to demonstrate the kind of problems the OCaml module signature notation is trying to tackle I wrote the following code in two files:

In file `ordering.ml` (or `.mli` — I've tried both) (*file A*):

```
module type ORDERING = sig
 type t
 val isLess : t -> t -> bool
end
```

and in file `useOrdering.ml` (*file B*):

```
open Ordering
module StringOrdering : ORDERING
  let main () =
    Printf.printf "%b" StringOrdering.isLess "a" "b"
  main ()
```

The idea being to expect the compiler to complain (when compiling the second file) that not enough type information is available on module `StringOrdering` to typecheck the `StringOrdering.isLess` application (and thus motivate the need for the `with type` syntax).
However, although file A compiles as expected, file B causes the 3.11.2 `ocamlc` to complain for a syntax error. I understood that signatures were meant to allow someone to write code based on the module signature, without access to the implementation (the module structure).

I confess that I am not sure about the syntax: `module A : B` which I encountered in [this rather old paper on separate compilation](http://web.mit.edu/16.399/www/project/OCaml/programs/separate-compilation/doc/separate-compilation.pdf) but it makes me wonder whether such or similar syntax exists (without involving functors) to allow someone to write code based only on the module type, with the actual module structure provided at linking time, similar to how one can use `*.h` and `*.c` files in C/C++. Without such an ability it would seem to be that module types / signatures are basically for sealing / hiding the internals of modules or more explicit type checking / annotations but not for separate / independent compilation.

Actually, looking at the [OCaml manual section on modules and separate compilation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual004.html) it seems that my analogy with C compilation units is broken because the OCaml manual defines the OCaml compilation unit to be the `A.ml` and `A.mli` duo, whereas in C/C++ the `.h` files are pasted to the compilation unit of any importing `.c` file.

Comment: As Thomas' answer momentarily said, there is no separate compilation by default for native compilation. I wish there were, and I entered a feature wish in mantis to this effect: http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=4389 . If anyone knows how to obtain separate native compilation in OCaml (as Thomas momentarily claimed was possible), I would be EXTREMELY interested in hearing about it.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Why do you say that you cannot separately compile native code in Ocaml? Of course you can.

Comment: Actually, I just modified the two files as suggested in Thomas's answer and indeed you can compile separately either bytecode (ocamlc) or native (ocamlopt).

Comment: @AndreasRossberg There is no room to repeat my feature wish here, but look at the output of `ocamldep`, which corresponds to the actual dependencies between `.cmx` files if you do not move them around to prevent the compiler inlining stuff from one into the other. Note that the wish was resolved in "won't fix", not in "no change necessary". See also "separate compilation" remarks in http://frama-c.com/u3cat/download/CuoqICFP09.pdf . These have never been challenged. I am glad to here there is separate native compilation in OCaml but many people think there isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right way to do such a thing is to do the following:

1. In ordering.mli write:

   ```
   (* This define the signature *)
   module type ORDERING = sig
     type t
     val isLess : t -> t -> bool
   end

   (* This define a module having ORDERING as signature *)
    module StringOrdering : ORDERING
   ```
2. Compile the file: `ocamlc -c ordering.mli`
3. In another file, refer to the compiled signature:

   ```
   open Ordering

   let main () =
     Printf.printf "%b" (StringOrdering.isLess "a" "b")

   let () = main ()
   ```

   When you compile the file, you get the expected type error (ie. `string` is not compatible with `Ordering.StringOrdering.t`). If you want to remove the type error, you should add the `with type t = string` constraint to the definition of `StringOrdering` in `ordering.mli`.

So answer to you second question: yes, in bytecode mode the compiler just needs to know about the interfaces your are depending on, and you can choose which implementation to use at link time. By default, that's not true for native code compilation (because of inter-module optimizations) but you can disable it.

Comment: Hey, your answer came back! Could you expand on the "you can disable it" part of your answer? Perhaps the feature wish I entered in mantis clarifies why this is important to me: http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=4389

Comment: The bug you are referring is about `ocamldep`. `ocamlopt` disables cross-module optimizations if it doesn't find the corresponding `.cmx` file in the path; if you link together compilation units built without cross-compilation that should work fine; if you mix things together, I don't really know what will happen :-)

Comment: Thanks, the two files now compile separately. Also, for this trivial example at least, I was also able to use ocamlopt to separately compile the two files even though I understand your answer to be that that's only possible with ocamlc.

Comment: @Thomas My bug report is an uncollapsed waveform of an `ocamldep` bug report and of an `ocamlopt` bug report. I will try moving files around to fool the compiler, though.

Comment: @Thomas It irks me that you have to actually name the module that has the signature. Also, in step 3 of your response, one does not "refer to the compiled signature" but rather to a "dummy" module (StringOrdering). This StringOrdering module is really a placeholder for the real implementation to be provided at link time. So, when the "real" StringOrdering.cmo is provided, the "open" statement in step 3 will have to change from `open Ordering` to something else. So I don't see real separate compilation when you have to change the sources for the actual linking. Or maybe I don't get something.

Comment: @MenelaosPerdikeas: This answer is vastly overcomplicating things if all you want to achieve is separate compilation. I don't recommend using this scheme unless you have an urgent need to name the module _type_ `ORDERING` apart from just the module.

Comment: I agree with Andreas: you never use such a scheme in practice, but I was answering to the questions by giving the right syntax.

Comment: @MenelaosPerdikeas In the signature, you say that you have somewhere a module with the right implementation, that you will provide at link-time. This is like a promise that you give to the compiler. The open statement just say you open the namespace defined by the signature `Ordering`, it doesn't say anything on the implementation that you will provide at link-time (which should be module named ordering.ml : if you have mulitple ordering.ml which have the right signature, you can choose to link with the one you want)

Answer (score 4):

You are probably just confused by the relation between explicit module and signature definitions, and the implicit definition of modules through .ml/.mli files.

Basically, if you have a file a.ml and use it inside some other file, then it is as if you had written

```
module A =
struct
  (* content of file a.ml *)
end
```

If you also have a.mli, then it is as if you had written

```
module A :
sig
  (* content of file a.mli *)
end =
struct
  (* content of file a.ml *)
end
```

Note that this only defines a *module* named A, not a module *type*. A's signature cannot be given a name through this mechanism.

Another file using A can be compiled against a.mli alone, without providing a.ml at all. However, you want to make sure that all type information is made transparent where needed. For example, suppose you are to define a map over integers:

```
(* intMap.mli *)
type key = int
type 'a map
val empty : 'a map
val add : key -> 'a -> 'a map -> 'a map
val lookup : key -> 'a map -> 'a option
...
```

Here, `key` is made transparent, because any client code (of the module `IntMap` that this signature describes) needs to know what it is to be able to add something to the map. The `map` type itself, however, can (and should) be kept abstract, because a client shouldn't mess with its implementation details.

The relation to C header files is that those basically *only* allow transparent types. In Ocaml, you have the choice.

Answer (score 3):

`module StringOrdering : ORDERING` is a module declaration. You can use this in a signature, to say that the signature contains a module field called `StringOrdering` and having the signature `ORDERING`. It doesn't make sense in a module.

You need to define a module somewhere that implements the operations you need. The module definition can be something like

```
module StringOrderingImplementation = struct
  type t = string
  let isLess x y = x <= y
end
```

If you want to hide the definition of the type `t`, you need to make a different module where the definition is abstract. The operation to make a new module out of an old one is called sealing, and is expressed through the `:` operator.

```
module StringOrderingAbstract = (StringOrdering : ORDERING)
```

Then `StringOrderingImplementation.isLess "a" "b"` is well-typed, whereas `StringOrderingAbstract.isLess "a" "b"` cannot be typed since `StringOrderingAbstract.t` is an abstract type, which is not compatible with `string` or any other preexisting type. In fact, it's impossible to build a value of type `StringOrderingAbstract.t`, since the module does not include any constructor.

When you have a compilation unit `foo.ml`, it is a module `Foo`, and the signature of this module is given by the interface file `foo.mli`. That is, the files `foo.ml` and `foo.mli` are equivalent to the module definition

```
module Foo = (struct (*…contents of foo.ml…*) end :
              sig (*…contents of foo.mli…*) end)
```

When compiling a module that uses `Foo`, the compiler only looks at `foo.mli` (or rather the result of its compilation: `foo.cmi`), not at `foo.ml`¹. This is how interfaces and separate compilation fit together. C needs `#include <foo.h>` because it lacks any form of namespace; in OCaml, `Foo.bar` automatically refers to a `bar` defined in the compilation unit `foo` if there is no other module called `Foo` in scope.

¹  <sub>Actually, the native code compiler looks at the implementation of `Foo` to perform optimizations (inlining). The type checker never looks at anything but what is in the interface.</sub>