# How to cast the type in functors OCaml

Tags: ocaml, functor

I've get the follow code about the functors in OCaml:

```
type comparison = Less | Equal | Greater;;

module type ORDERED_TYPE =
    sig
        type t
        val compare: t -> t -> comparison
    end
;;

module Set =
    functor (Elt: ORDERED_TYPE) ->
        struct
            type element = Elt.t
            type set = element list
            let empty = []
            let rec add x s =
                match s with
                | [] -> [x]
                | hd :: tl ->
                    match Elt.compare x hd with
                    | Equal -> s
                    | Less -> x :: s
                    | Greater -> hd :: add x tl
            let rec member x s =
                match s with
                | [] -> false
                | hd :: tl ->
                    match Elt.compare x hd with
                    | Equal -> true
                    | Less -> false
                    | Greater -> member x tl
    end
;;

module OrderedString : ORDERED_TYPE = 
    struct
        type t = string
        let compare x y =
            if x = y then Equal
            else if x < y then Less
            else Greater
    end
;;

module StringSet = Set(OrderedString);;

let out = StringSet.member "foo" (StringSet.add "foo" StringSet.empty);; (*compile error, where "foo" is expected OrderedString.t but actually is string*)
```

The above error can be avoided by eliminating the `: ORDERED_TYPE` in `module OrderedString : ORDERED_TYPE =`

Just can't understand why.

Analogously, if there is any type in a module like

```
module A = struct type t = string end;;
```

How can I specify a string value as the type `A.t` but not an actual `string`

Thanks.

Comment: I found this reading useful as I couldn't figure what was happening there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778595/ocaml-functors-counter-intuitive-behaviour .

Answer (score 5):

You can look at how it is done in the standard library : [set.mli](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/set.mli).
The signature of the functor is

```
module Make (Ord : OrderedType) : S with type elt = Ord.t
```

the `with type elt = Ord.t` part indicates that the `elt` type is not abstract.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Tomash, you're lacking a type constraint, but not in the functor signature (there isn't any in your code in fact), but in the argument you're giving to it. Basically, when you write

```
module OrderedString : ORDERED_TYPE = struct ... end
```

the definition of the type `t` in `OrderedString` will be abstracted away, since `t` is an abstract type in the `ORDERED_TYPE` signature. What you want here is to say that `OrderedString` is indeed an implementation of `ORDERED_TYPE`, but with a known type `t`. This is exactly what you'll get with

```
module OrderedString: ORDERED_TYPE with type t = string = struct ... end
```